# ObjectUnsubscribedError when navigating in event handler

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I got a navigation service

```
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class NavigationService
{
    @Output() navigating = new EventEmitter();
    navigate(param: number) {
    this.navigating.emit({ param})
    }
}
```

which I subscribe for in my `app.component`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _router: Router,
        private _navigationService: NavigationService) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    this._navigationService.navigating
        .subscribe(data => {
            this._router.navigate(['SomeView', { param: data.param}]);
        })
    }
}
```

Navigation actually happens, but on the console I get this error:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ObjectUnsubscribedError
>   browser_adapter.ts:73

(cut for brevity).

I don't know what to make of this, my guess is that 'AppComponent' is unsubscribed from `navigating`, but that shouldn't matter should it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `Output` decorator in services:

```
@Output() navigating = new EventEmitter();
```

Should be simply:

```
navigating = new EventEmitter();
```

The `@Ouptut` decorator is for components that want to expose custom events.

Comment: Ok, changed that, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Could you provide the whole stack trace for your error? Thanks!

Comment: Got it, was a stray `<a href="#"></a>` around the element that fired the original event, thanks for the hint though, Thierry.